# ssh-agent, ssh-add on eshell in gnu emacs on surface pro 3

Tags: windows

My macbook pro recently died. :-(

I am using my surface pro 3.

I have gnu emacs + haskell installed.

I am using eshell inside of emacs as my shell.

I have ssh installed (via git).

Now, ssh-add + ssh-agent do not work.

How do I make ssh-add and ssh-agent work? (as I need to get git push to work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two CLI choices for git on windows. You can chose to use the git shell, where ssh-agent and ssh-add will work. I believe you can launch this from one of the full terminal emulators in emacs, like *term*, as long as you can find its install path.
It might work in eshell too, though I think you'll lose syntax highlights there. If you prefer to use POSIX-style tools, you can also try out *Cygwin*, which is what I do personally. Then the emacs that comes with Cygwin will default to Cygwin's shell and will use Cygwin's git.

But if you need to do more than git pull and git push over ssh, you may wish to check out emacs' tramp mode. Here you again have two choices: putty (see [this article](http://hoardedhomelyhints.dietbuddha.com/2012/11/configing-emacs-tramp-with-putty.html)), or Cygwin.

Of course, if you really prefer unices, you can try [running Linux on your surface pro](http://redmonk.com/gearmonk/2014/10/29/a-linux-guy-tries-a-surface-pro-3-you-wont-believe-what-happens-next/).